# way to detect mobile device with small physical screen, but with full hd pixel resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile

is there some "best-practice" to detect mobile devices, which physically have small screen, but with high pixel definition?
for example some smartphones has and 4.7 inch screen size, and at the same full-hd 1920x1080. i need to show mobile header on site instead of standart desktop, and use css query for this. for example

```
@media (max-width: 1024px){

    #responsive_mobile_header{
        display: block;
    }

    #desktop_header{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

this works for a big amount of devices, but for full-hd mobile i need another way...

regexp also not the best way - new browsers and new id appear suddenly, they will not be detected

Comment: You can use `min-device-pixel-ratio` or `min-resolution` (in dpi). See [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) and [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/) for more info.

Comment: Have a look at this :) https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery)

Comment: i already saw this. but i think regex - it's not the best way. but thanks for link, maybe someone else will use it).

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thx i try to use it!